# Retrieving bank withdrawals from Paypal

Tags: php, paypal

Is there any way to retrieve bank withdrawals using the Paypal API?
It says here:
https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_r_GetTransactionDetails
That "The details for some kinds of transactions cannot be retrieved with GetTransactionDetails. You cannot obtain details of bank transfer withdrawals, for example."
But is there any way around it? I really need to retrieve this data.

Thanks.

Comment: Why does PayPal not want you to retrieve this data? And why do you think you should be able to?

Comment: I am not really sure why Paypal does not want me to retrieve it, but I know it can be retrieved using the Paypal export options. Just not using the API. For example this is from the export option:    4-May 12:40:15 Bank Account Withdraw Funds to a Bank Account USD -700.00  3B641262315412053